# Consulta en mysql eliminando resultados de cero

Tags: php, mysql

Buenos días una vez mas consulto a la comunidad para ver si me pueden ayudar, tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT ncuenta, dcuenta, SUM(-saldo) as monto2
FROM captura
WHERE SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,2) >= '30'
and SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,2) < '39'
and fecha <= '2017-09-30'
GROUP BY NCUENTA
```

En donde el resultado que da es el siguiente:

```
+---------+---------------+------------+
| ncuenta | dcuenta       | monto2     |
+---------+---------------+------------+
| 310-012 | revision      |      -0.00 |
| 320-005 | presupuesto   |       0.00 |
| 321-001 | datos ultimos | 5712934.19 |
+---------+---------------+------------+
```

Y me da la consulta bien pero quisiera que la consulta me diera sin los cero, es decir asi:

```
+---------+---------------+------------+
| ncuenta | dcuenta       | monto2     |
+---------+---------------+------------+
| 321-001 | datos ultimos | 5712934.19 |
+---------+---------------+------------+
```

solamente alguien que me pueda ayudar o que tenga alguna idea de como puedo hacerlo

Comment: Podrías agregarle una condición mas que sea monto2 < 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con:

```
SELECT ncuenta,dcuenta,SUM(-saldo) as monto2 FROM captura WHERE SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,2)>='30'and SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,2)<'39' and fecha<='2017-09-30'  GROUP BY NCUENTA HAVING SUM(-saldo)>0
```

Comment: ya la probe y me sale Invalido uso de función en grupo

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó

Answer (score 1):

> Puedes agregar en el where 2 condicionales pegados con un operador AND
>   para que haga ambas comparativas incluyendo que sea mayor a 0

```
SELECT ncuenta, dcuenta, SUM(-saldo) as monto2
    FROM captura
    WHERE 
       (SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,2) >= '30') AND
       (monto2 > 0)
    and SUBSTR(NCUENTA,1,2) < '39'
    and fecha <= '2017-09-30'
    GROUP BY NCUENTA
```

> Revisa muy bien que para poder pasar mas condiciones al WHERE las
>   separo entre paréntesis y separadas por el operador AND